# Google Shell Style: what is ${E_DID_NOTHING}?

Tags: bash, shell, styles

In the [Google Shell Style](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/shell.xml?showone=STDOUT_vs_STDERR#STDOUT_vs_STDERR), here's how to handle errors:

```
err() {
  echo "[$(date +'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')]: $@" >&2
}

if ! do_something; then
  err "Unable to do_something"
  exit "${E_DID_NOTHING}"
fi
```

Can someone explain to me what's going on in this statement?

```
exit "${E_DID_NOTHING}"
```

Comment: Really not much. Calling exit with whatever that variable contains.

Comment: Constant exit status for "Unable to do something" to allow easier classification of errors later presumably.

Comment: I see. Thanks. Is the brace expansion necessary? `exit "$E_DID_NOTHING"` should work, I believe, so I was wondering why the brace expansion.

Answer (score 0):

Every linux command line after executing, returns a status code/exit code..this code take any value between the range 0 to 255.

A status code of 0 means successful

Any other status code other than 0 represents some type of error

```
exit "${E_DID_NOTHING}"
```

`${E_DID_NOTHING}` - substitute the variable with the use  brace expansion and then execute exit with this code

Comment: I see. Thanks. Is the brace expansion necessary? `exit "$E_DID_NOTHING"` should work, I believe, so I was wondering why the brace expansion.

Comment: No...it is not..but your code has it which is not incorrect neither...you haven't included the value for "$E_DID_NOTHING" in your codes..I suppose, this variable is in the other part of your codes..if there is no value for this variable, then the script will just execute "exit"  without any return status